# Rails: Route nested resource to parent resource view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to route the following urls:

```
/sections/8
/sections/8/entries/202012
/sections/8/entries/202012#notes
```

to `SectionsController#show`

and for `params[:id]` to be `8` for all urls and for `params[:entry_id']` to be `202012` when present.

How can I accomplish this with routes?

I've already got:

```
resources :sections, only: [:show]
```

Comment: If you want all the url's starting with '/sections/' to go the sectioncontrollers show action try: match '/sections/', to: 'sections#show', via: 'get'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is to identify what you want these routes to do. They are structured such that rails will want to route them as follows

```
resources :sections, only: [:show] do
  resources :entries, only: [:show]
end

# /sections/8 => SectionsController#show
# /sections/:id
#
# /sections/8/entries/202012 => EntriesController#show
# /sections/:section_id/entries/:id
#
# /sections/8/entries/202012#note => EntriesController#show
# /sections/:section_id/entries/:id
```

However if you're wanting all of these to map to SectionsController you could change the first route to follow the restful routes.

```
resources :sections, only: [:show] do
  resources :entries, only: [:index, :show], controller: 'sections'
end

# /sections/8/entries => SectionsController#index
# /sections/:section_id/entries
#
# /sections/8/entries/202012 => SectionsController#show
# /sections/:section_id/entries/:id
#
# /sections/8/entries/202012#note => SectionsController#show
# /sections/:section_id/entries/:id
```

If you're determined to make all of these routes go to a single controller, which I would not advise, then you can define your routes explicitly.

```
get '/sections/:id', to: 'sections#show'
get '/sections/:id/entries/:entry_id', to: 'sections#show'
```

To use these routes you'll use the rails url helpers. Let's take this code as an example since it mostly resembles what you seem to be asking for.

```
resources :sections, only: [:show] do
  resources :entries, only: [:index, :show], controller: 'sections'
end
```

`section_entries_path` is the helper for your index view. and `section_entry_path` is the helper for your show view. If you have the records you need (ie, section record with id 8 and entry record with id 202012), then you can pass them to the helper.

```
section = Section.find(8)
entry = section.entries.find(202012)
section_entry_path(section, entry) # => returns path string /sections/8/entries/202012
```

For more information read the rails routing guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html and try to understand segment keys and named path helpers.

Comment: Thanks. Going with this: `resources :sections, only: [:show] do
  resources :entries, only: [:index, :show], controller: 'sections'
end`

Answer (score 1):

In routes

```
resources :sections do
  resources :entries 
end
```

In EntriesController#show method

```
redirect_to section_path(id: params[:section_id], entry_id: params[:id])
```